# Query to distribute amounts with remainder across multiple line items in a group

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008

I have a need for a query that will recalculate amounts across multiple line items in a group and account for any remainders in the last line item amount.

Currently I am accomplishing this by manually looping through the ordered results - using variables to store, calculate and distribute the values.  This is highly inefficient when querying large amounts of data.

Here is a sample of code to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish:

```
if exists(select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id('tempdb.dbo.#xpayments'))
    drop table #xpayments


create table #xpayments (
    payment_id int,
    payment_amount decimal(10,2),
    payment_fee decimal(10,2),
    lineitem_id int,
    lineitem_amount decimal(10,2),
    lineitem_fee decimal(10,2))

insert into #xpayments (payment_id, payment_amount, payment_fee, lineitem_id, lineitem_amount, lineitem_fee) values (1,16.00,1.37,1,10.00,0)
insert into #xpayments (payment_id, payment_amount, payment_fee, lineitem_id, lineitem_amount, lineitem_fee) values (1,16.00,1.37,2,5.00,0)
insert into #xpayments (payment_id, payment_amount, payment_fee, lineitem_id, lineitem_amount, lineitem_fee) values (1,16.00,1.37,3,1.00,0)
```

Note: payment amount and payment_fee are sum values for the entire payment - all line items.

```
select * from #xpayments
```

results in:

```
payment_id  payment_amount  payment_fee lineitem_id lineitem_amount lineitem_fee
1           16.00           1.37        1           10.00           0.00
1           16.00           1.37        2           5.00            0.00
1           16.00           1.37        3           1.00            0.00
```

Now calculate and distribute the lineitem_fee for each line item as follows:

```
update #xpayments set lineitem_fee = payment_fee * (lineitem_amount/payment_amount)
```

results in:

```
payment_id  payment_amount  payment_fee lineitem_id lineitem_amount lineitem_fee
1           16.00           1.37        1           10.00           0.86
1           16.00           1.37        2           5.00            0.43
1           16.00           1.37        3           1.00            0.09
```

Now check the results:

```
select payment_id, payment_amount, payment_fee, sum(lineitem_amount) lineitem_sum, sum(lineitem_fee) lineitem_fee_sum 
from #xpayments 
group by payment_id, payment_amount, payment_fee
```

results in:

```
payment_id  payment_amount  payment_fee lineitem_sum    lineitem_fee_sum
1           16.00           1.37        16.00           1.38
```

As you can see, because of rounding, the calculated fee sum is greater than the actual fee.

Is there an easy way to calculate and use the remainder for the final line item fee in a query statement?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of one UPDATE statement you can have below two update statements. This should give you expected results.

```
UPDATE X set lineitem_fee = payment_fee * (lineitem_amount/payment_amount)
FROM #xpayments X JOIN (SELECT MAX(lineitem_id) LastLineItemID,payment_id FROM #xpayments GROUP BY payment_id) S
    ON S.payment_id=X.payment_id
WHERE X.lineitem_id < S.LastLineItemID

UPDATE X set lineitem_fee = payment_fee - lineitem_fee_sum
FROM #xpayments X JOIN (SELECT MAX(lineitem_id) LastLineItemID,sum(lineitem_fee) lineitem_fee_sum,payment_id FROM #xpayments GROUP BY payment_id) S
    ON S.payment_id=X.payment_id
WHERE X.lineitem_id = S.LastLineItemID
```

Comment: This works for the scenario described in the original question. Thank you.  However, I should have qualified my test case a little better.  How can I apply this same logic to multiple groups?  In other words, what if I have more than 1 payment_id?

Comment: @PatrickRBaggett: I have modified the UPDATE statements to cover the additional test scenarios.

Comment: Hope the updated query gave you the expected results. Please mark it as answer.